# Lookup list with dependencies/permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, custom-list, lookup-column, splistitem

Below is a drawing of a scenarium I want to create in SP2013. My question is wether this is possible OTTB, or possible at all.

The main concern is, how possible is it to make drop-down depend on each other. That is if I choose one item in the first drop-down, then only items related to that item is possible to choose from the next drop-down.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to make custom forms with Visual Studio C # ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have cascading dropdowns (behavior that you are describing) in OOTB SharePoint forms. There are third party solutions (both farm solution and add-ons) that add this functionality to lists. You can also have a look at SPServices jquery library and add this functionality yourself to the form. This does require some javascript development knowledge. Here is a tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using.

SPServices library can be downloaded here: https://spservices.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that the SPService is the way to go, it looks like something easy enough to implement, and there seems to be alot of guids on how to.

Another question. If one wants to go a step further and populate some of the lists with some external data (make them dynamic), instead of manually create the items. Maybe use some Navision tables to derive data from or other tables in a Databse. In which direction should I look then?

I would not be creating this by myself, but I would have to have a clear idea if it is possible and how to proceede.

Comment: SharePoint offers functionality for including external data, for example a SQL table. There are some prerequisites you have to have in place (on farm level, infrastructure, authentication etc.) but once all that is taken care of you can create external content types and external lists. Some background info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063.aspx. You can also use external content types to get data from webservices.